# Standard deviation problem

Tags: statistics

Let's say I have mean quality of 50 and standard dev of .1. And I the requirements for any product must be of quality 45 or higher. How do I calculate the chances that the quality of a product is greater than 45?

Comment: Is the quality distributed normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a one-sided version of Chebyshev's inequality, $$\Pr(X - \mu  \leq -k \sigma) \leq \frac{ 1 }{ 1 + k^2 }$$  though in this rather extreme case the two sided version will give much the same bound

Here $50-45$ is $50$ times the standard deviation, so the probability that a sample of the product is less than or equal to $45$ is less than or equal to  $\frac{1}{2501}$ so the probability it is more than $45$ is greater than or equal to $\frac{2500}{2501} \approx 0.9996$.

That can be a rather loose bound. If you knew the distribution was Gaussian, then that final figure would be about $1-10^{-545}$ which is extremely close to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You need to know the distribution to do that. All you can do if you only know the mean and standard deviation is to bound the probability using [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality).

Comment: Oh... darn :s I thought it would've been simpler than that. Thanks!